# Button breaks in nested sweet_alert in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, sweetalert

In this application, I have two nested sweet_alert popups, which are similar to Shiny's modalDialogs.

There is a button inside the first alert which activates the second alert. The second alert then pops up replacing the first alert.

On the first round everything works correctly. After that, the second button stops working.

Steps to follow:

1. Click Button1 -> see alert 1
2. Click Button2 -> alert 1 replaced with alert 2
3. Press OK, closing alert2
4. Click Button1 -> see alert 1
5. Click Button2 -> Nothing happens

Why does Button2 break after the first round? And how to fix?

```
library('shinyWidgets')
ui = fluidPage(
    actionButton("btn1", "Button1")
)

server = function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$btn1, {
        show_alert(
        title = "This is the first popup!",
        text = tags$div(
            actionButton("btn2", "Button2")
        ),
        html = TRUE,
        width = "80%"
        )
    })

    observeEvent(input$btn2, {
        show_alert(
        title = "This is the second popup!",
        html = TRUE,
        width = "80%"
        )
    })
}
runApp(shinyApp(ui, server))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to resolve that is to use `closeSweetAlert()` to reset btn2.  Try this

```
library('shinyWidgets')
ui = fluidPage(
  actionButton("btn1", "Button1")
  #,verbatimTextOutput("t1")
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$btn1, {
    show_alert(
      title = "This is the first popup!",
      text = tags$div(
        actionButton("btn2", "Button2")
      ),
      html = TRUE,
      width = "80%"
    )
  })
  
  output$t1 <- renderPrint(input$btn2)
  
  observeEvent(input$btn2, {
    closeSweetAlert(session = shiny::getDefaultReactiveDomain())
    show_alert(
      title = "This is the second popup!",
      html = TRUE,
      width = "80%"
    )
  })
}
runApp(shinyApp(ui, server))
```

Comment: Thank you @YBS. Thank you. This helped me, after 3 hours to research.